# PHP session store data before flush

Tags: php, laravel

I am storing some data in variables like this,

```php
$dbs_office = $request->session()->get('dbs_office');
$reference = $request->session()->get('reference');
$request->session()->flush();
return view('confirmation', ['ref' => $reference, 'dbs_team' => $dbs_office]);
```

I was hoping that by storing some of the session data in their vars I would be able to persist the data past the flush, however the vars are empty when I check. Is there a way to store these bits of data for use in a view, but remove the session data totally?

Comment: Are you sure they are not empty even before the `flush()` occurs? And what type of data are you storing in Session?

Comment: You should check `variable` not empty before you `flush`. If your `variable` is empty before `flush`, check your `session`.

Comment: They are not empty before the flush happens, but when used in the view they are empty. They are used in the view after the flush.

Comment: What type of variables are?

Comment: They are Strings

Comment: Try to comment out the `$request->session()->flush();` line. Are the variables still empty?

Comment: no they are not

Comment: Why do you need to flush the session?

Comment: You should try first to log the vars, just to confirm if they are not empty. Then you should check if by some any other method you do the session()->flush() also.

Comment: I tried your exact code and the variables passed to the view are not empty even after flush(). Tested on php 7.3.7. So you should have some other kind of problem